# Calculating n-dimensional Image Entropy Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, entropy

I am trying to calculate the entropy on higher dimensional "images". The obvious approach:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy

kernel_radius=2
entropy_stack = np.zeros(Stack.shape)
for ii in range(kernel_radius,entropy_stack.shape[0]-kernel_radius):
    for jj in range(kernel_radius,entropy_stack.shape[1]-kernel_radius):
        for kk in range(kernel_radius,entropy_stack.shape[2]-kernel_radius):    
            entropy_stack[ii,jj,kk]=entropy(Stack[ii-kernel_radius:ii+kernel_radius,jj-kernel_radius:jj+kernel_radius,kk-kernel_radius:kk+kernel_radius].flatten())
```

works but is painfully slow.

Are there any implementation tricks to calculating entropy in higher dimensional images? even better: are there any packages with an optimized version of this function?

I know scikit-image's `entropy` does a good job but only in 2D. Similarly I know matlab's `entropyfilt` which performs a couple hundred times faster than my current implementation.

Comment: FYI, `entropy` in scipy.stats expects probabilities, not values.

Comment: Also, `entropy` implements the entropy calculation for a stream of symbols, not for a stream of ordinal numbers. I would suggest that you look into binless estimators of entropy or that you -- at the very least -- bin the values in your image stack into less than 256 different classes/symbols (assuming you are saving your images in uint8 arrays).

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that unfortunately turned out to be just as slow (albeit being much cleaner code and handling the boundaries properly). It uses the `generic_filter` in `scipy.ndimage`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
from scipy.stats import entropy

def _entropy(values):
    probabilities = np.bincount(values.astype(np.int)) / float(len(values))
    return entropy(probabilities)

def local_entropy(img, kernel_radius=2):
    """
    Compute the local entropy for each pixel in an image or image stack using the neighbourhood specified by the kernel.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    img           -- 2D or 3D uint8 array with dimensions MxN or TxMxN, respectively.
                     Input image.
    kernel_radius -- int
                     Neighbourhood over which to compute the local entropy.

    Returns:
    --------
    h -- 2D or 3D uint8 array with dimensions MxN or TxMxN, respectively.
         Local entropy.

    """
    return generic_filter(img.astype(np.float), _entropy, size=2*kernel_radius)
```

Comment: Thank you. This version is definitely cleaner. I will have to take a look at the difference between inputing values and probabilities to 'entropy()'